# Ejecutar comando multi-línea después de reiniciar sesión

Tags: bash, shell

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que crea un micro-servicio y para probarlo realizo llamadas con curl desde un terminal de BASH. El comando tiene varias líneas para facilitar su legibilidad, y cuando tengo que repetirlo simplemente pulsando la flecha para arriba funciona correctamente. Por ejemplo:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost/miServicio -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
    "parametro1" : "valor1",
    "parametro2" : "valor2",
    "parametro3" : "valor3",
    "parametro4" : "valor4",
    "parametro5" : "valor5",
    "parametro6" : "valor6"
}'
```

El problema viene cuando cierro sesión en el terminal y vuelvo a abrirla. Entonces si pulso hacia arriba para ver comandos anteriores, me muestra mi comando línea a línea y no el comando completo, lo cual no me vale.

Igual ocurre si hago `history` o intento ejecutar el comando usando `!` y su número en el historial. Por ejemplo, si hago `history | grep curl` y veo que mi comando era el 256, si ejecuto `!256` no corre el comando completo, sólo carga la primera línea y se queda esperando más.

¿Se puede ejecutar un comando multi-línea después de reiniciar sesión? ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: Perdón, habia que escapear: Has probado agregar "\"  al final de cada linea que continua en la siguiente? Por ejemplo: `... -d  '' { \\`, etc.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Voy a probar y te digo

Comment: A ver si puedes sacar alguna conclusión de [este hilo](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-02/msg00025.html), donde se plantea tu mismo problema, el autor del mismo lo reportaba como un bug, pero es de 2009 y puede que tenga que ver más bien con la configuración del histórico.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho no funcionó, de hecho se rompió el comando (quizás porque no lo estoy poniendo bien).

Comment: @A.Cedano Es exactamente el problema que tengo. Gracias por el enlace, voy a ver si alguien encontró respuesta

Comment: Acabo de probar los comandos del enlace que te paso A. Cedano con el uso de la \ para indicar la continuación de la linea, en una terminal Cygwin (Bash en Windows) y pareciera funcionar.

Comment: No, miento al salir e reiniciar, se vuelve a perder la funcionalidad esperada

Comment: Alvaro ¿y no podrías crear un archivo con esos comandos y evitar el problema?

Comment: @A.Cedano Eso es lo que hice al final, crear un pequeño script al que llamo. Pero tenía curiosidad por saber si se podía hacer de otra manera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alvaro, te cuento como he podido implementar esta funcionalidad para ver si te sirve:

#### Configurar opciones para el history en `.bashrc`

```
$ shopt -s cmdhist
$ shopt -s lithist
```

Según la documentación:

> **cmdhist**   If set, bash attempts to save all lines of a multiple-line
>             command in the same history entry.  This allows  easy  re-editing 
>             of multiline commands.
>
> **lithist**   If  set,  and the cmdhist option is enabled, multi-line
>   commands 
>             are saved to the history with embedded newlines rather than using 
>             semicolon separators where possible.

Y por último:

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%h %d %H:%M:%S "
```

Con esto establecemos un formato para guardar en el `history`, el cual nos quedaría algo así:

```
    1  Jan 11 14:03:48 history
    2  Jan 11 14:03:55 echo "como \
estas"
    3  Jan 11 14:04:02 history
    4  Jan 11 14:07:31 notepad .bashrc
    5  Jan 11 14:07:35 notepad2 .bashrc
    6  Jan 11 14:11:33 history
```

y físicamente el archivo, luego de reiniciar la sesión

```
#1515690228
history
#1515690235
echo "como \
estas"
#1515690242
history
#1515690451
notepad .bashrc
#1515690455
notepad2 .bashrc
#1515690693
history
#1515690741
less .bash_history
#1515690777
cat .bash_profile
#1515690783
cat .bash_history
#1515690894
curl -X POST http://localhost/miServicio -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{
    "parametro1" : "valor1",
    "parametro2" : "valor2",
    "parametro3" : "valor3",
    "parametro4" : "valor4",
    "parametro5" : "valor5",
    "parametro6" : "valor6"
}'
#1515690907
history
```

Si vemos ahora incorpora un delimitador entre cada comando producto de agregar el `HISTTIMEFORMAT`, lo cual haría más fácil para bash la interpretación de los comandos. La contra es que la visualización del `history` ahora agregaría más información que tal vez no la necesites.

Fuente: [When is a multiline history entry (aka lithist) in bash possible?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/353386/when-is-a-multiline-history-entry-aka-lithist-in-bash-possible)

Comment: Buena solución, no conocía `lithist` y resulta muy útil.

Comment: No he conseguido que me funcione. Sí, el comando me aparece separado en el history, pero cuando reabro sesión y uso los cursores del teclado para ir arriba en el historial, me siguen apareciendo línea a línea en lugar de todos juntos.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, lo he probado sobre CygWin en Windows y funcionaba, lo probaré igual a la noche en un Linux real y te cuento. Has incorporado los comados `shopt -s cmdhist` y `shopt -s lithist`  en la inicialización del Bash?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, en un bash 4.38.48 sobre un Linux mint 18 te confirmo que esto lamentablemente no funciona. En un Cygwin - Bash 4.4.12 funciona perfecto. Seguiré investigando.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho casi te diría que pongas ese comentario como una nota en la respuesta. Al final opté por crear un pequeño fichero que ejecutara esto sin necesidad de hacer nada más y no creo que merezca la pena invertir más tiempo ver en qué versiones de bash funciona o no.